# Reading text file and searching for a number

Tags: vb.net

I did search a lot about this but found nothing. So, I simply have 1 textbox, 1 label called "Invalid", 1 button, and finally a text file.

The text file has numbers in lines or more likely zip codes written in this way:

```
10000
23251
30021
51931
and so on...
```

- textbox = type the zip code number
- button = to search if the number which I did type in the textbox is inside the text file or not. If yes, then `label1.text = "Valid"`

and that's pretty much all of it.

I tried the following but I know it's totally wrong + it doesn't work + it will take so long time to type each and every single number in it.

Can someone provide a method and a code to use and apply it directly not to mention understanding it as I'm new regarding VB.NET stuff.

I tried File.ReadAllLines, was searching about some documentations but I only did find C# not VB.NET

Someone told me to used File.ReadAllLines as shown:

```
If linesFromFile.Any(Function(l) l = myTextBox.Text) Then
    label1.Text = "Valid"
End If
```

Tried to apply it but no good.

```
Dim File As String = "Georgia.txt"
Dim Georgia As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(File)
If Georgia.Any(Function(l) l = TextBox1.Text) Then
Label1.Text = "Valid"
End If
```

Comment: _"I tried the following"_ Did you forget to include what you tried? Please [edit] the question and include your code.

Comment: Welcome! Take the [tour]. Please edit your question and include the code you have tried.

Comment: Read the file into a in memory collection such as List(Of String), then you can do something like use the Contains() method to check if valid or not

Comment: @AndrewMortimer done, I added what I've tried

Comment: @Hursey I tried the File.ReadAllLines but it didn't work out, create new txt file in the project itself

Comment: File.ReadAllLines() returns a String Array. Try Dim Georgia = IO.File.ReadAllLines(File) or Dim Georgia As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(File)

Comment: 1) Set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project and make it the default for new projects. It will let Visual Studio help you with coding. 2) Use the full path of the file. 3) It is a bad idea to give variables the same name as a class in VB - e.g. `File` would be better as `filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a process to find a match. There are many ways to do this.
Create a form called frmTest add two buttons btnFind and btnLoad then a Textbox called tbFind.Also you will need a ListBox named ListBox1.
In my example I load the data into a String Array called strData.
It needs to be declared top level like this `Dim strData(12) As String`
Now that the data is in the String Array load the strData in to the ListBox.
Enter the value you want to find into the tbFind
Now click the btnFind.

```
Dim strData(12) As String

Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    LoadLB()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadLB()
    strData = {"", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}
    Dim allMo As String
    For i As Integer = 1 To 12
        allMo = i & " - " & strData(i)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(allMo)
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub btnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click

    For x As Integer = 1 To 12
        If tbFind.Text = strData(x) Then
            MsgBox("Match " & strData(x))
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```